# Unix root no access to directory with 000 permissions

Tags: unix, permissions, nfs

I have a directory with the following permissions:
d---------    8 nobody     60001

Root can not delete this directory or change the permissions. Any ideas to get this removed from the system?

Tried rm -rf, chmod, chown, mv while Root

Comment: potential title change: "Permission Impossible - Nobody's Dir"

Answer (score 0):

Although i'm giggling too much to read the documentastion specific to this case, what you need is to employ a Linux Security Module (LSM) to do the cleanup for you. The two most popular LSM solutions are AppArmor and SELinux. Congratulations for getting that far up the creek without a paddle.